# Loopback 3.2.1 polymorphic belongsTo relation filter not working

Tags: postgresql, loopbackjs, belongs-to

I'm using Loopback 3.2.1 with postgresql connector. I have this polymorphic `belongsTo` relation defined in the Question model:

```
"relations": {
  "related": {
    "type": "belongsTo",
    "model": "questionable",
    "polymorphic": true
  },
}
```

But querying on related model gives a 500 error `"Relation \"related\" is not defined for Question model"`

There seems to be a related [issue # 1319](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/1319) in the github repo that was opened on Apr 21, 2015.

Is there a workaround on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up defining the polymorphic relation in the model JavaScript file:

```
Question.belongsTo('questionable', {
  as: 'related',
  polymorphic: true
});
```

This works for me, and gets the related polymorphic relation. Hope this helps others, and the Loopback team resolves this issue soon.